# How can i group candidates by their post in html page

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net, deployment

i want to group my data based on category in asp.net

I have two tables one with voting positions and another one with voting candidates, so for each position i want to list all candidates under that position and move to next without repeating position on every candidate row

```
   <asp:Repeater ID="rptVoteParti" runat="server" >
                    <ItemTemplate>         
                            <div class="row fs-5 py-2 border-bottom text-uppercase">
                            <asp:Label ID="Label31" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Post")%>'/>
                            </div> 
                            <div class="row py-2"> 
                         
                                <div class="card-body bg-light">
                                <p class="px-2"> <asp:Image  runat="server"  ImageUrl='<%# Eval("Picture") %>' Height="300px"  alt=""/> </p>
                                <p class="px-2 text-uppercase text-success fw-bold">FULL NAME : <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>'/> </p>
                                <p class="px-2 text-uppercase text-success fw-bold">Part Name : <asp:Label ID="Label1x" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Part")%>'/> </p>
                                <p class="px-2 text-uppercase text-success fw-bold">Program :<asp:Label  runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Program")%>'/> </p>
                           
                                 <div class="form-check">
                                  <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="flexRadioDefault" id="flexRadioDefault1">
                                  <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
                                    Vote
                                  </label>
                                  </div>

                                    <div class="form-check">
                                      <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="" id="defaultCheck1">
                                      <label class="form-check-label" for="defaultCheck1">
                                        Vote Yes
                                      </label>
                                    </div>

                                </div>


                            </div> 
                </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:Repeater>
```

this in my code but it repeat the position on every row

Answer (score 1):

So, if you think about this, we have a row we want to display, and then some child records for each row.

So, in most cases, I recommend a list view, since they tend to make layout a lot easier. But, let's do this with a repeater.

So, first let's setup a repeater that displays the parent data. In this example, we display some hotels.

Then when that is working, for each hotel, we will display the child records (people booked in that hotel).

So, say we have this markup:

(we deal with child table information in a bit).

so, this markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:HiddenField ID="HotelID" runat="server" Value='<%# Eval("ID") %>' />
        <div style="float:left;border:solid 1px;width:40%;padding:8px">

            <div style="float:left">
                <h4>Hotel Information for <%# Eval("HotelName") %> </h4>
                <h5><i>Description</i></h5>
                    <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Eval("Description") %>'
                        width="300px" >
                    </asp:Label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater>
```

And code to load is this:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then
        LoadGrid()
    End If

End Sub


Sub LoadGrid()
    Dim strSQL As String

    strSQL = "SELECT * FROM tblHotelsA 
             ORDER BY HotelName"

    Repeater1.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
    Repeater1.DataBind()

End Sub
```

And now we have this:

[image]

So, all good.

Now, let's add to the repeater, for each "one thing" - in this case the hotel.

So, since we have repeating data? Well, ok, then we need a control that allows "repeating" of data.

We could drop in (nest) another repeater). However, let's go with a grid view.

So, we add this to our markup:

```
            <div style="float:left;margin-left:30px">

                <h5>Bookings</h5>
                <asp:GridView ID="GVPeople" runat="server" 
                    CssClass="table"
                    width="100%">
                </asp:GridView>

            </div>
```

Now, we need to fill out the grid view of people for each hotel. We use the ItemData bound event.

So, that code is this:

```
Protected Sub Repeater1_ItemDataBound(sender As Object, e As RepeaterItemEventArgs) Handles Repeater1.ItemDataBound

    ' for each repated item and gridview, fill out GV
    If e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.Item Or
        e.Item.ItemType = ListItemType.AlternatingItem Then

        Dim HotelPK As Integer =
            CType(e.Item.FindControl("HotelID"), HiddenField).Value

        ' load up GV
        Dim MyGV As GridView = e.Item.FindControl("GVPeople")
        Dim strSQL As String =
            "SELECT FirstName, LastName, City FROM People WHERE Hotel_ID = " & HotelPK

        MyGV.DataSource = MyRst(strSQL)
        MyGV.DataBind()

    End If

End Sub
```

And now we see/get this:

[image]

So, you can drop in a grid view, or even another repeater inside of the existing one. You then have to deal with "each" row of the parent repeater, get the child object (repeater, listview, gridview), fill it out.

so, ItemData bound triggers for each row - we use that event to fill out the grid view for each row of the repeater.

And of course, to save wearing out a keyboard, I used this helper routine:

```
Public Function MyRst(strSQL As String) As DataTable

    Dim rstData As New DataTable
    Using conn As New SqlConnection(My.Settings.TEST4)
        Using cmdSQL As New SqlCommand(strSQL, conn)
            conn.Open()
            rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader)
        End Using
    End Using
    Return rstData

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks you very much its work, but i like if you can help with the list method

Comment: Hum? I am confused and don't understand? I don't see anything about some list method here? The markup was a repeater (which I used in my example).  And as noted, for each row of the repeater, you need something that also can display repeating data. I used a gridview, but you can use a nested repeater, or you can even use a listbox, or even a listview, or in my case a gridview. But, I don't grasp what "list" method you are talking about. Maybe start a new question, but I don't grasp what you asking about here? To list out many things, use a gridview like per this example.

Comment: Okay thanks i think this method you send me works fine, let me leave the list its complicated...thank you very much.